# How can I set the time zone in Dockerfile using gliderlabs/alpine:3.3

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile

My Dockerfile is:

```
FROM gliderlabs/alpine:3.3
RUN set -x \
    && buildDeps='\
        python-dev \
        py-pip \
        build-base \
    ' \
    && apk --update add python py-lxml py-mysqldb $buildDeps \
    && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/* \
    && mkdir -p /app
ENV INSTALL_PATH /app
ENV TZ=Asia/Shanghai
WORKDIR $INSTALL_PATH
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone
COPY requirements-docker.txt ./
RUN pip install -r requirements-docker.txt
COPY . .
RUN apk del --purge $buildDeps
ENTRYPOINT ["celery", "-A", "tasks", "worker", "-l", "info", "-B"]
```

I setted the timezone as `Asia/Shanghai`, but it did not work and gave me the UTC which had 8 hours deviation, the result is :

```
2016-01-24 11:25:07:[2016-01-24 03:25:07,893: WARNING/Worker-2] 2016-01-24 03:25:07.892718
2016-01-24 11:25:08:[2016-01-24 03:25:08,339: INFO/MainProcess] Task tasks.crawl[98c9a9fc-0817-45cb-a2fc-40320d63c41a] succeeded in 0.447403368002s: None
2016-01-24 11:27:07:[2016-01-24 03:27:07,884: INFO/Beat] Scheduler: Sending due task spider (tasks.crawl)
```

Then I tried other methods like:

```
RUN echo "Asia/Shanghai" > /etc/timezone && dpkg-reconfigure -f noninteractive tzdata
```

and

```
RUN ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Shanghai /etc/localtime
```

none of them did work, how can set the timezone? Thanks very much.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The usual workaround is to mount `/etc/localtime`, as in [issue 3359](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/3359#issuecomment-38134906)

```
$ docker run --rm busybox date
Thu Mar 20 04:42:02 UTC 2014
$ docker run --rm -v /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro  busybox date
Thu Mar 20 14:42:20 EST 2014
$ FILE=$(mktemp) ; echo $FILE ; echo -e "Europe/Brussels" > $FILE ; docker run --rm -v $FILE:/etc/timezone -v /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Brussels:/etc/localtime:ro busybox date
/tmp/tmp.JwL2A9c50i 
Thu Mar 20 05:42:26 CET 2014
```

The same thread mentions (for ubuntu-based image though), but you already tried it.

```
RUN echo Europe/Berlin > /etc/timezone && dpkg-reconfigure --frontend noninteractive tzdata
```

(And [I referred before to a similar solution](https://serverfault.com/a/683606/783))

---

Another option would be to build your own [**`gliderlabs/docker-alpine`**](https://github.com/gliderlabs/docker-alpine/) image with [`builder/scripts/mkimage-alpine.bash`](https://github.com/gliderlabs/docker-alpine/blob/3fe0456981e67f140b0d441e367838105e30fd2e/builder/scripts/mkimage-alpine.bash#L18).

That script allows you to [set a timezone](https://github.com/gliderlabs/docker-alpine/blob/3fe0456981e67f140b0d441e367838105e30fd2e/builder/scripts/mkimage-alpine.bash#L47-L48).

```
    [[ "$TIMEZONE" ]] && \
        cp "/usr/share/zoneinfo/$TIMEZONE" "$rootfs/etc/localtime"
```

You can see that image builder script used in [Digital Ocean: Alpine Linux](https://github.com/bontibon/digitalocean-alpine):

> ### Generate Alpine root file system

- Ensure Docker is running locally.
- Download and unzip [`gliderlabs/docker-alpine`](https://github.com/gliderlabs/docker-alpine).

  ```
  wget -O docker-alpine-master.zip https://github.com/gliderlabs/docker-alpine/archive/master.zip
  unzip docker-alpine-master.zip
  ```
- Build the builder ([export the right timezone first](https://mm.icann.org/pipermail/tz/2001-April/011541.html)).

  ```
  export TIMEZONE=xxx
  docker build -t docker-alpine-builder docker-alpine-master/builder/
  ```
- Build the root file system (change v3.3 to the Alpine version you want to build).

  ```
  docker run --name alpine-builder docker-alpine-builder -r v3.4
  ```
- Copy the root file system from the container.

  ```
  docker cp alpine-builder:/rootfs.tar.gz .
  ```

Once you have the `rootfs.tar.gz` on your own filesystem, you can use it (as [mentioned here](https://hashnode.com/post/how-do-you-build-your-own-docker-image-with-zero-dependencies-cim0utz0g01qygb533ixw7xnf)) to build your own Alpine image, with the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM SCRATCH
ADD rootfs.tar.gz /
```

Once built, you can use that Alpine image with the right timezone.

Comment: How do I set the timezone? When I edit [this line](https://github.com/gliderlabs/docker-alpine/blob/master/builder/Dockerfile#L4) to `ENTRYPOINT ["/mkimage-alpine.bash" "-t" "Europe/Berlin"]` and try to run the new image, I get `/bin/sh: [/mkimage-alpine.bash: not found`

Comment: @Munchkin this is the exec form of entrypoint (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint) and it should work if you build (not run) the image: `docker build`.

Comment: Ah sorry, I forgot the colons... but when I run my new image (after bulding with the customized ENTRYPOINT) it stops immediatly: `docker run -it mygliderlabs /bin/sh`

Comment: @Munchkin which makes sense: a container stops as soon as its entrypoint/commanbd process stops.

Comment: I don't understand why the mkimage-alpine.bash is defined as ENTRYPOINT instead of RUN command. What's the reason for this? When I change it to a RUN command, I can /bin/sh into the container. But when I execute `date` in that container, I get now `Fri Nov 11 06:27:29 UTC 2016` - which is mmore than 1 day in the past. I'm confused.

Comment: @Munchkin Because it is made to build an image, which in turn you will run. So running that container stops immediately and produces a new image that in turn you can run.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128000/discussion-between-munchkin-and-vonc).

Comment: @Munchkin I am back (for a few minutes): ADD will extract the `tar.gz` for you right at the root folder `/`. The goal is to build an image from that rootfs archive. Once the image is built, you can launch a container like any other image.

Comment: @Munchkin See https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/add: If `<src>` is a local tar archive in a recognized compression format (identity, gzip, bzip2 or xz) then it is unpacked as a directory. That is one of the differences with `COPY` (which does not uncompress an archive)

Answer (score 6):

//dockerfile

```
RUN apk update && apk add tzdata \
     && cp -r -f /usr/share/zoneinfo/YOUR_TIMEZONE /etc/localtime
```

Comment: Can you explain your changes and why you made them?

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help. A proper explanation would [greatly improve](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) its educational value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions. Please edit your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: copy timezone file to container to reset its timezone

Comment: This works in an Alpine based container.   It tells the container host to update the apk cache (apk update) and then install the application tzdata into the host (apk add tzdata).  It next makes a copy of a TIMEZONE file from the host and writes it to /etc/localtime in the container (cp -r -f /usr/share/zoneinfo/TIMEZONE /etc/localtime).    TIMEZONE should be whatever is appropriate for your use ... for me it is /usr/share/zoneinfo/US/Eastern.  The container, when it runs, will use that timezone as established by /etc/localtime.

Answer (score 0):

I‘m running my Docker on Mac Mojave,
In Dockerfile, I added the following after many failed tries:

ENV TZ=Asia/Shanghai
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone && \
    apt-get install tzdata && \
    dpkg-reconfigure --frontend noninteractive tzdata

And it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

To Set timezone in Dockerfile you can use those lines

```
ENV TZ=Africa/Douala
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone
```