# Running python script inside Docker container wrong timezone

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, datetime

I'm running a script inside a Docker container (python:3.6) and it shows me the wrong time in the logs. When using the following python code in the python console(inside the container) it gives me the correct timezone.

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime.now()
datetime.datetime(2019, 8, 3, 17, 26, 25, 662809)
```

Also, when running the `date` command inside the container, it gives the correct timezone.

However, I have this print statement in my script:

```
print("Updating....", datetime.datetime.now())
```

This however, gives me the wrong timezone (2 hours off).

[image]

This is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    container_name: app
    build: .
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      TZ: Europe/Amsterdam
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    container_name: db
    image: mariadb
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: x
      MYSQL_DATABASE: x
      MYSQL_USER: x
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: x
      TZ: Europe/Amsterdam
    volumes:
      - /volumes/x/db:/var/lib/mysql
```

This is my crontab file (runs inside the app container)

```
CRON_TZ=Europe/Amsterdam

*/5 * * * * cd /usr/src/app && /usr/local/bin/python3.6 -u -m x > /proc/1/fd/1 2>/proc/1/fd/2
0,30 * * * * cd /usr/src/app && /usr/local/bin/python3.6 -u -m x > /proc/1/fd/1 2>/proc/1/fd/2
5 0 * * * cd /usr/src/app && /usr/local/bin/python3.6 -u -m x > /proc/1/fd/1 2>/proc/1/fd/2
```

I tried setting the timezone in `docker-compose.yml`, that worked for `date` command and the python console. I tried setting the timezone inside the crontab file, but it still doesn't show the correct timezone in the script.

How do I set the timezone for Python inside a crontab, so that the logs do have the correct timezone? Also, I need to run a script at 00:05 not 22:05, does that work now?

Comment: Is it when you run the script as a cronjob that you get the wrong time? It looks like the time you get is UTC, since Central European Summer Time is UTC+02:00

Comment: I'm not sure if debian/ubuntu's version of cron uses the CRON_TZ env variable at all. (the default python docker images are debian based) I think you have to change the system timezone in the container as suggested in the answer by @nick-rundle. There's no mention of CRON_TZ in the manpage for [crontab (5)](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/cron/crontab.5.en.html) for debian 10 "buster"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got burned by this same problem a while back. Unfortunately, I don't remember the exact fix that ended up working. But here are some pointers:

1) The problem is with Docker, not Python or datetime or anything else. Docker containers struggle to know what the time is. What you want to search for is ways to sync up time inside a container with host.

2) There are many suggested ways of handling time in containers, but I remember them all being work-arounds of sorts. Last I checked there was no clear solution.

3) I would HIGHLY recommend that you do not put cron jobs inside containers. If you need things to run at a certain time, put the crons ON THE HOST, and have them spin up the containers when needed. This is much more reliable.

Comment: For those of you how are wondering what he is trying to say, he is telling you add this line ` ENV TZ="Africa/Lusaka" `. Thanks. @Neil

Comment: can someone [edit] the post to integrate more details (like the timezone fix above) into the answer? thanks

Comment: For anyone looking directly at this answer, while it is correct, the answer you are probably looking for is from Nick Rundle. You need to copy /etc/localtime from the host into the container. You can do that with 'volumes' in docker compose or -v with docker run.

Answer (score 8):

If you are trying to sync the timezone in the container with the host machine, you can map the timezone setting from the host.  I've done this successfully with the following volume:

`-v /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime`

Or in your docker-compose.yml file:

```
volumes:
    - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime
```

Comment: It's also possible to use a different timezone in the container. Europe/Amsterdam is Central European Time, so this should work. `/usr/share/zoneinfo/CET:/etc/localtime`. (at least for debian/ubuntu. The path might be different in other distros). It should also be possible to do at build time in the Dockerfile (as root). `ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/CET /etc/localtime`

Answer (score 3):

For most users, setting the environment variable as below for your Python container in your `docker-compose.yml` should be sufficient and effective:

```yaml
   environment:
      TZ: America/New_York
```

This was tested with CPython 3.8. Remember to recreate and not merely restart your container after setting it.

---

Credit: comment by Harsh Nagarkar.

Comment: This should be `TZ=America/New_York` (equal sign instead of colon). Otherwise, I can confirm that this works great !

Comment: @Avandale environment can be either a map or an array. If its a map its correct like in this answer. If its an array its `- key=value` note the leading dash.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use time.tzset() in the beginning of your code or you can use :

```
import detetime
import pytz

datetime.now(tz=pytz.timezone('Europe/Amsterdam'))

# or datetime.now(tz=pytz.timezone(os.environ.get('TZ'))
```

also, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34972521/how-can-i-set-the-time-zone-in-dockerfile-using-gliderlabs-alpine3-3)

Answer (score 0):

What is extremely strange, is that I have a python script writing the time to a log (among other things).

```py
import time 
print(time.strftime("%c"))
```

will return 'Tue Mar 15 14:25:31 2022' for example.
If I connect to the container and start python3 and do the commands manually, it returns 'Tue Mar 15 15:25:31 2022'

the container has the timezone set as TZ parameter and if I run 'date' from the shell in the container, the time is indeed the intended localtime. If I omit the TZ, it's reverts to UTC time.

I was forced to pass the TZ as a parameter to the python script and process it.

```py
import time
import os
os.environ['TZ'] = a
time.tzset()
print(time.strftime("%c"))
```

where 'a' is that passed parameter

It's quite clear in my github project: https://github.com/TrueOsiris/docker-godaddypy as this only has a Dockerfile, one bash script and one python script.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by passing `TZ` environment variable to the container and providing a converter function to the `logging.Formatter.converter` as specified in https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html.

According to https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/tick-tock-container-time, "Usually, the time zone is set to the location where the image or base image was built, or to UTC±00:00". Therefore, I passed timezone to podman container using `--tz=<time-zone>` parameter. If it is a `podman play kube` you can pass `TZ` value as an environment variable as below. This will set the timezone of the container.

```
....
spec:
  containers:
  - name: python
    env:
    -name: TZ
     value: "Asia/Colombo"
....
```

Then I modified my python code to assign a converter function. Since I wanted the container's local time (i.e "Asia/Colombo") I assigned below to the converter.

`logging.Formatter.converter = time.localtime`

Answer (score 0):

Tell your docker container which time zone it should use, while building the image.

For example, with a dockerfile, install `tzdata` and set the `ENV` var `TZ`. More explanation, and instructions for docker Engine and Compose [see here](https://gist.github.com/sjimenez44/1b73afeae3eec26a1915b0d4d5873b8f).

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
 
# tzdata for timzone
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y tzdata
 
# timezone env with default
ENV TZ=America/Bogota
```